# Cannot dynamically create namespace node for xsi:type attribute

Tags: xslt, xml-namespaces, xsitype

Assume

```
<myDoc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:js="urn:myJS1"
       xmlns:ns="urn:myNS1">
   <myElem1  xsi:type="ns:myComplexType"/>
   <myElem2 xsi:type="js:myComplexType"/>
</myDoc>
```

I want to migrate this doc to  use version 2 of the namespaces but need to do this dynamically because I can't predict which values of xsi:type are in the instance. Also ideally I want the same prefixes.  So I want something like

```
<myDoc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   <myElem1  xmlns:ns="newNs" xsi:type="ns:myComplexType"/>
   <myElem2 xmlns:js="newNs" xsi:type="js:myComplexType"/>
</myDoc>
```

My best effort intercepts the creation of the xsi:type attribute and tries to create a namespace node for the new version. It is not working.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
version="2.0">

    <xsl:variable name="schemas">
        <thing targetNamespace="newNs"/>
    </xsl:variable> 

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


     <xsl:template match="@xsi:type">
      <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">       
         <xsl:namespace name="{substring-before(.,':')}" select="$schemas/thing/@targetNamespace"/>
         <xsl:next-match/>       
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but this does not result in an instance showing the new namespace nodes.

Although my example is XSLT 2.0, an XSLT 3.0 solution to this is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `match="@xsi:type"` template, the context node is the `@xsi:type` attribute itself, so selecting `@xsi:type` is wrong, it should simply be `.`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
version="2.0">

    <xsl:variable name="schemas">
        <thing targetNamespace="newNs"/>
    </xsl:variable> 

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


     <xsl:template match="@xsi:type">
         <xsl:namespace name="{substring-before(.,':')}" select="$schemas/thing/@targetNamespace"/>
         <xsl:next-match/>       
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have corrected that now but it still does not work as intended.

Comment: You also need to drop the xsl:copy - the body of an xsl:copy instruction is ignored when copying an attribute. https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9HjZj

Comment: Yes. I see it has worked in the cut down example, sadly it does not yet work with my actual code. I shall have to come back to this.

Comment: Ok I've found my bug. If you would like to correct the answer to your comment above I will accept it. Thanks Mike.